# Highlight Borders When Mouseover Fill Area - Leaflet-R

Tags: r, leaflet-r

Following the guidance of TimSalabim I separated the borders and fill of my neighbourhood polygons so that I could order them appropriately with zIndex.

https://lawsblog.netlify.com/post/leaflet-map/

Now if I place the highlightOptions() function within the addPolygons(neighbourhood fill) function I don't know how to increase the border of the polygon.

If I place the highlightOptions() function within the addPolylines(neighbourhood border) function I can CAREFULLY mouse over just the border and its width increases.

So now that I've separated the fill and borders of the polygons how do I increase the border width when I mouseover the fill area?

```
# Add hood borders
  addPolylines(data = borders, 
               color = "white",
               opacity = 1, 
               weight = 2,
               options = pathOptions(pane = "hood_borders")) %>% 

 # Add hood fill
  addPolygons(data = hood_shp,
              fillColor = ~pal(be_per_cap),
              fillOpacity = 1.0,
              color = NA,
              options = pathOptions(pane = "hoods",

              # Highlight neighbourhoods upon mouseover - NOT CORRECT
              highlight = highlightOptions(
                          stroke = 4),

              # Add label info when mouseover
              label = labels,
              labelOptions = labelOptions(
                style = list("font-weight" = "normal", padding = "3px 8px"),
                textsize = "15px",
                direction = "auto")))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think if you add `weight` argument to your `highlightOptions()`, the border width should change on hover. For example:

```
 addPolygons( 
   ...
   highlightOptions = highlightOptions(stroke = 4, weight = 2),
   ...)
```